# Pass Attribute as a Component Parameter in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, binding, vue.js

I'm creating a test Component in Vue.js. I want to pass a parameter to use in my template as follows:

```
Vue.component('test', {
   props: ['href'],
   template: '<li><a href="{{href}}"><slot></slot></a></li>'
});
```

In my html file:

```
<test href="/">Tvest</test>
```

But the property `href` is not binding to the attribute.

```
<li><a href="{{href}}">Tvest</a></li>
```

How can I do it properly in Vue.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [get rid of the brackets](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) around `href` and specify that you are binding a data property by using the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind):

```
<li><a v-bind:href="href"><slot></slot></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [v-bind directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to set the prop:

`<a v-bind:href="href"><slot></slot></a>`

or shortcut

`<a :href="href"><slot></slot></a>`

Comment: My component disappear when I put in this way

Comment: I copied your brackets... :( . Of course brackets are a two way binding that only works as innerContent of html-elements.